How to change the replace and merge using built-in settings sync in vscode vscode
How to choose to replace and merge using the built-in settings sync in vscode? And if I initially chose a replacement strategy, but I don't want to always replace it, can I still make changes and how should I modify it?. I am using vscode version 1.84.
I have consulted some materials, but there is no clear and feasible solution.
